# Not all components required for linking are present on the command line

Tags: c++, intel, tbb

I'm trying to use Intel Threading Building Blocks using Intel Parallel Studio XE 2013 (Intel C++ 14.0 project). I have the following to my code

```
#include <tbb/tbb.h>
using namespace tbb;
```

and am trying to operate on a `map<char, concurrent_vector<int>> stats`, specifically to perform an operation such as `stats[x].push_back(y)`.

and have set the 'Use Intel TBB' option in project properties. When I try to compile, I get an error saying

```
Error   10  error #11023: Not all components required for linking are present on command line   C:\Dropbox\Projects\Games\Preference\Preference\ipo Preference (Intel C++ 14.0)
```

With subsequent errors complaining that I have unresolved externals such as `tbb::internal::concurrent_vector_base_v::internal_push_back(...)`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you enable IPP option?

Comment: @herohuyongtao yes, as single-threaded static library

Comment: Show your linking option. It seems that you miss some library.

Comment: Which Visual Studio version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to include tbb_debug.lib into you linking process or to disable auto-linkage to it. Try defining __TBB_NO_IMPLICIT_LINKAGE

Comment: Nope, this didn't help :(